# ios7 uisearchbar statusbar color

Tags: colors, ios7, uisearchbar, statusbar

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UISearchBar` in it , a blue top bar and I set the status bar to white icons on ios7 so I can see them on the blue background.

While I perform a search though the blue top bar disappears and the white background of the screen hides the status bar content.

So, I would like to set the status bar color to Default (black) while searching and to white again while the search is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just hit this problem. Your options are limited. Either tint your search bar to a darker color, or set its style to `UIBarStyleBlack` to have a dark search bar.